# Ingresar nombre de la Tabla con un un PreparedStatement (PHP -Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, datatables, prepared-statements

## Buenas! 
Les comento mi problema:

> Mi problema esta al querer crear una tabla para una base de datos
> usando PrepareStatement y utilizando un holder para asignarle el
> nombre a la tabla.  
> El código del "Ejemplo1" funciona
> perfectamente, el tema es que por una cuestión de seguridad me
> gustaría hacerlo como en el "Ejemplo2", pero la syntax no es correcta.

*¿Cómo se usa el holder (':tabla') en ese caso? ¿Es inseguro si lo hago como en el primer ejemplo?*

**EJEMPLO 1 (Funciona sin problemas):**

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tabla (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)");
$statement->execute();
```

**EJEMPLO 2 (Error de Syntax):**

```
$statement = $conexion->prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :tabla (id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, apellido VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL)");
$statement->execute(array(':tabla' => $tabla));
```

**ERROR:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near ''nombres' (reg INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
> nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NUL...' at line 1 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi_LocalHost\Enunciados\1\borrar.php:14 Stack trace:
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi_LocalHost\Enunciados\1\borrar.php(14): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\Mi_LocalHost\Enunciados\1\borrar.php on line 14

Comment: Ayudaría mucho a la comunidad si anexas el mensaje de error que estás obteniendo

Comment: La documentación dice: *”No se pueden vincular usando parámetros una parte del literal, ni una palabra clave, ni un identificador...”*

Comment: La variable $tabla del primer ejemplo ya está definida o de algún modo el usuario la introduce?

Comment: @MRDev La variable $tabla es introducida por un formulario y recibida en el .php. A lo que recibo le aplico "FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING" antes de guardarla en $tabla.

Comment: @Sal Dale, muchas gracias. Soy bastante nuevo en el mundo de la programación y hay bastantes cosas que desconozco. ¿Donde puedo encontrar la documentación que acabas de citar?

Comment: La documentación está en [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php).